# @3x are not shown in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode6, xcasset, iphone-6-plus

I'm notice when I've have installed the Xcode 6 (GM) and I load a project from Xcode5, in the Images.xcassets file the @3x option is not shown for any image with Universal Devices.

Answer (score 2):

Click on `Images.xcassets` in your binary and click on plus down below (or right click) and add App Icons and Launch Images. If they are already showing then select them and see the right bar (red circle in photo) how to select additional **iOS 8** versions:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning an option is Change each image Universal to Specific, select retina 4 inches and then select Universal again.

But the best option is remove the derive data folder, go to:

Preferences -> Location -> Derive data folder and remove the folder with your project.

Then build and that works for me.

Happy to share this with you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in Xcode (6.0.1) - take a look at your.xcassets/*/Contents.json - there is nothing about @3x. I just added all the necessary stuff to my .appiconset by hand in json according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) you can check it on [my gist](https://gist.github.com/Czajnikowski/daf31d9f84e34e267671)